# Conflicting date ranges for COPERNICUS/DEM/GLO30 in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, dem, geemap, copernicus, imagecollection

I'm trying to filter DEMs from the COPERNICUS/DEM/GLO30 ImageCollection in Google Earth Engine by date. However, the date range I'm getting from the collection seems incorrect, leading to filtering issues. The dataset should cover 2010-2015, but my code indicates it starts in 2006.

[image: Picture of the homepage of the ImageCollection stating the dataset Availability]

I wanted to filter by date and got an empty image every time, so I tried this code in code editor:

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/DEM/GLO30')
var range = collection.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.minMax(), ['system:time_start'])
print('Date range: ', ee.Date(range.get('min')), ee.Date(range.get('max')))
```

Resulting in this output:

```
    "Date range: "
{
  "type": "Date",
  "value": 1136073600000 (2006-01-01)
}

{
  "type": "Date",
  "value": 1136073600000 (2006-01-01)
}
```

I usually do not use the code editor, as I am not used to program in Java Script. Instead I work with geemap. I got a similar date result there however.

Has anyone else encountered this or know how to resolve it? I'm looking for help in understanding and fixing this date discrepancy.

Answer (score 0):

The original dataset doesn't include any information about the date of collection; it's just a big mosaic from a bunch of data.  Why all the images dates are set to 2006 is a question, but there's no time data there to be had.